# Windows XP cannot execute binary file on Network Share

Tags: windows, mac-osx, network-share, mac-osx-server, server-message-block

I'm having a Network Share provided by a Mac OS X Lion Server on a recent Mac Mini Server (CIFS / SMB); mounting the share in Windows (XP) is no problem, reading and writing neither. But when ever I try to execute an executable `.exe`, Windows complains that it's not a valid win32 executable.
Copying the file from the network share to the desktop or some other local location, allows the file to be subsequently executed.
Pointers to what the root cause of this problem may be are greatly appreciated.

Comment: UNIX-based systems typically don't set the execute permission bit on files by default.  Perhaps you need to change the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting to the server?  Since the program works when you copy it locally, you might want to add the server to the Intranet security zone.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303650